# how to use ribbon category to switch view?

Tags: mfc, ribbon

I want to use two ribbon category buttons to switch between two different views, but I found it can't add event handler to the button.

Is there any hint to solve this problem? Better if there is some sample, actually I'm new to MFC.

Answer (score 2):

You could try hooking into this event?

AFX_WM_ON_CHANGE_RIBBON_CATEGORY

Answer (score 0):

An option I have found successful was to subclass CMFCRibbonBar and override PreTranslateMessage and check for mouse clicks.  Below are the steps I took which have thus far worked well.

1. Subclass CMFCRibbon - in my example I created CCustomRibbonBar
2. Override PreTranslateMessage, and add an int value to keep track of the tab
3. Create a custom windows message that your applications MainForm handles -WM_ACTIVE_RIBBON_TAB_CHANGED in my example
4. Inside of PreTranslateMessage check for Left Mouse Up event
5. In the event of a left mouse button up, let the Ribbon finish handling the message and then query the Active Category.
6. Post the active category to MainForm (or other form)
7. In your MainForm, handle the category and take into account that with most events the category will not have changed.

Then in my override I check for the mouse up event and retrieve the Active category

**Inside Class Declaration**

```
  virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
    int m_LastActiveCategory;
```

**Inside Class Definition**

```
BOOL CCustomRibbonBar::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    //If command was finishing a click
    if(pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONUP && pMsg->wParam == 0)
    {

        //Allow ribbon to handle itself first
         BOOL result = CMFCRibbonBar::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);

         //Get new active tab
         int activeTab = GetCategoryIndex(GetActiveCategory());

         //If tab has changed, forward message
         if(activeTab != m_LastActiveCategory)
         {
              //forward message to parent
            ::SendMessage(GetParentFrame()->GetSafeHwnd(),WM_ACTIVE_RIBBON_TAB_CHANGED,activeTab,0);
            m_LastActiveCategory = activeTab;
         }



         return result;
    }

    //Otherwise handle like normal
    return CMFCRibbonBar::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```